# Electrical and plumbing dielectric myth or fact

Tags: electrical, plumbing, wiring

I heard it's good to keep certain wires (mc cable notably) from resting on copper water pipes as to keep any potential dielectric breakdowns from happening. Is this just a myth or a fact and should I be concerned about when wiring electrical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metal / copper can create a problem. I have not found the insulation to be damaged but have found the points of contact created holes in the copper pipe and rusty spots on the metal. The pipe had failed in multiple locations under the house and the copper had to be replaced but the MC was ok even though water had been spraying on it.  I have seen several times when copper to galvinised pipe were made a metal union (it should a dielectric union) the pipes failed in a short number of years / months. I believe there is a photo on this site where chicken wire was used to hold up insulation and the wire was in contact with the Copper pipe and that pipe had started to fail. Not a myth copper and other metals can cause pipe failure, but I have not seen the insulation damaged.

Comment: My suspicion is that most of those failures were due to the external agent (wiring) causing condensation to occur and inhibiting evaporation, rather than any direct electrical effect.  It is true that mating different types of metal pipes, with water flow inside, creates a half-cell reaction and will lead to damaged pipes at the junction.